# Find and export a number from a line using a Bash command

Tags: awk, replace, scripting, export

I have a large text file that contains thousands of lines and I need to extract a number which lives on a specific line.

For instance, some lines in the text file appear as follows:

```
  19700    307.30459   -8158.4284            0   -8121.8045   -23047.162    29171.514 
  19800    300.74023   -8157.6228            0   -8121.7812   -23758.868    29219.884 
  19900    302.34994   -8159.1197            0   -8123.0863   -23360.949    29266.787 
  20000          300   -8165.4452            0   -8129.6919   -23585.616    29316.622
```

What is the best way to extract the last number on the line beginning with 19900 and export it to a new text file? This process is happening within a loop, so ideally I would be making this exported number a new line in a separate text file.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always recommended to add your effort in your post which you have put in order to solve the problem in code tags.

Comment: I apologize, I was unaware but will be mindful in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^19900/{print $NF}' Input_file
```

Above will print last field of Input_file's line which is starting from `19900` use following in case you want to print specific line.

```
awk '$1 == 19900 {print $7}' Input_file
```

As per @Cyrus comment adding following solution too now.

```
awk '$1==19900 && $0=$NF'  Input_file
```

Comment: Or `awk '$1 == 19900 {print $7}' Input_file`, which may be closer to the requirements.

Comment: @KenY-N, sure thanks for letting know. I added this solution in mine now, cheers.

Comment: or `awk '$1==19900 && $0=$NF' file`

Comment: @Cyrus, sure, I have added it now in my solution :)

Comment: Thank you very much, the awk function helped me do what I was trying to!